# How To Run Nested Async Functions In Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, python-2.x

Can anyone help me figure out how to run MethodTwo() asynchronously with the rest of the program?

Here is the code:

```
import asyncio
from asgiref.sync import sync_to_async

def MethodTwo():
    print("MethodTwo")

async def MethodOne():
    print("MethodOne")
    await sync_to_async(MethodTwo)()

async def Main():
    print("Main")
    await sync_to_async(MethodOne)()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(Main())
loop.close()
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: what is the problem with your current code ? the bug happens in `sync_to_async(MethodOne)` ... not in `MethodTwo`

Comment: It's telling me: TypeError("sync_to_async can only be applied to sync functions.")

Comment: you have a typo, `MethodOne` is already an async function, don't call `sync_to_async(MethodOne)()` instead just `MethodOne()`.

Comment: Why did you add the tag "python-2.x"?  The module asyncio wasn't added until version 3.4.

Answer (score 1):

With the `asyncio.to_thread()` method (added in Python3.10) this is easy.

```
import asyncio
import time

def MethodTwo():
    print("MethodTwo")
    time.sleep(2.0)
    print("MethodTwo done")

async def MethodOne():
    print("MethodOne")
    await asyncio.sleep(2.5)
    print("MethodOne done")

async def Main():
    print("Main")
    asyncio.create_task(asyncio.to_thread(MethodTwo))
    await MethodOne()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(Main())
```

If you want to use earlier versions of Python, you can achieve the same thing using a ThreadPoolExecutor. It takes a few more lines of code, but it works the same way.

The function `to_thread` is basically a wrapper around a ThreadPoolExecutor.

Executing a sync function in the main thread of an asyncio program will block the event loop.  If the function is fast that's not a problem, and is quite normal in any program.  But if the function takes a while to execute, then other tasks will be stopped.  I think that's what you're really asking.   There is no solution possible without using secondary threads or processes.